# How to deal with embeded html in xml with jq yq xq (xml to yaml conversion)

Tags: xml, jq, yq, xq

I have an xml dictionary file based on the [xdxf dictionary format here](https://github.com/soshial/xdxf_makedict) that I would like to convert (and round trip) to yaml.

This format (with DTD) may contain `<kref>` (cross reference) elements around a word that is already surrounded by `<deftext>` tags (definitions).  Or it may contain for example `<sub>` tags to indicate a word in subscript. I have not been able to see how to manage xml to yaml conversion of these files with yq (either the go or python) version.

#### An abreviated sample.xml (from the xdxf repo)

```
<lexicon>
    <ar>
        <k id="fb982hk">Society</k>
        <def>
            <deftext>Plural form of word <kref>index</kref>.
            </deftext>
        </def>
    </ar>
    <ar>
        <k>CO
            <sub>2</sub>
        </k>
        <def>
            <deftext>Carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>) - a heavy odorless gas formed during respiration.
            </deftext>
        </def>
    </ar>
  </lexicon>
```

#### converted to yaml via yq (go) will render:

```
 yq -p=xml -o=yaml < sample.xml 
lexicon:
  ar:
    - k:
        +content: Society
        +@id: fb982hk
      def:
        deftext:
          +content:
            - Plural form of word
            - .
          kref: index
    - k:
        +content: CO
        sub: "2"
      def:
        deftext:
          +content:
            - Carbon dioxide (CO
            - ) - a heavy odorless gas formed during respiration.
          sub: "2"
```

#### converted to yaml via yq (python) will render:

```
 xq < sample.xml | yq -y 
lexicon:
  ar:
    - k:
        '@id': fb982hk
        '#text': Society
      def:
        deftext:
          kref: index
          '#text': Plural form of word .
    - k:
        sub: '2'
        '#text': CO
      def:
        deftext:
          sub: '2'
          '#text': Carbon dioxide (CO) - a heavy odorless gas formed during respiration.
```

In both cases the `<kref>` and `<sub>` elements will no longer 'surround' the correct text and a return to xml will not be correct either.  Is this just a limitation of the format?  Or is there some way to accomodate (or maybe ignore as xml?) these tags?

Comment: If `<sub>` is meant to be literal text, then the XML is wrong: it should be `&lt;sub&gt;`

Comment: What would be a correct representation of this XML with YAML?

Comment: Yeah I'm just wondering.   <sub> is in the DTD as an xml element.  <!ELEMENT sub (#PCDATA)>  (link to repo above)  But maybe it shouldn't be.   To get it right in yaml it would have to come out as something like:   CO&lt;sub&gt2&lt;/sub&gt  But even if that were the case would it get back to xml intact?

Comment: And what about: <deftext>Plural form of word <kref>index</kref>.
            </deftext>  Is that ok syntax?  Note the period after the closing kref inside the deftext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The XML syntax isn't the problem.

You're struggling with the (general) way both [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) and [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) chose to represent the XML tree in JSON/YAML. There is no canonical solution to that, and both these approaches are lossy wrt to "Complex Types with Mixed Content", i.e. element nodes embedded into floating-around text nodes.

#### But modifying the XML syntax may be a solution.

If you don't care about the markup information conveyed by the elements in question, you could flatten out these passages in a pre-processing step, e.g. using a simple XSL transformation like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="kref|sub">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses a template matching `node()|@*` which just replicates all elements and attributes, and another one that overrides this behavior for the `kref` and `sub` elements by copying over just their textual content.

Apply this XSLT to your XML document using an XSLT processor such as `xsltproc`, `Saxon`, or `Xalan`, and you should get the stripped version of your input:

```xml
<lexicon>
  <ar>
    <k id="fb982hk">Society</k>
    <def>
      <deftext>
        Plural form of word index.
      </deftext>
    </def>
  </ar>
  <ar>
    <k>CO2</k>
    <def>
      <deftext>
        Carbon dioxide (CO2) - a heavy odorless gas formed during respiration.
      </deftext>
    </def>
  </ar>
</lexicon>
```

This can then be applied to your original `xq`/`yq` pipeline.

Comment: Thanks!   I see the issue.  And it would prob be ok to lose the <sub></sub> formatting.   But not the <kref>.   What would have to be in the xslt to match only <krefs> that are inside <deftext>?   As in the sample above.  Otherwise there are other krefs (not shown) that would need to be preserved.   (Sorry I didn't think this would evolve into xslt!)

Comment: @Boyd To only match a `<kref>` if it is a child of `<deftext>` (together with any occurrence of `<sub>`), adjust the (second) template accordingly, e.g. `match="deftext/kref|sub"`. If you're altogether uncomfortable using an XSLT or creating a new XML (which may break validity according to the original DTD), you can still go down the other rabbit hole and find another XML-to-JSON/YAML processor/converter that maps these structures (more) according to your needs.

Comment: @Boyd Or, if the final structure isn't too ramified, just compile it yourself, e.g. using the [HTML-XML-tools](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) (`hxselect` in particular). I have used that for a similar problem (maintaining the position and order of duplicate children) while converting XHTML files into JSON.

Comment: Thank you for all these suggestions.   I will try all to see what works best.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick-and-a-bit-hacky solution, and if you want to preserve the HTML-specific "markup", you could do worse than:

```
sed -E -e 's/<(kref|sub)>/!\1>/g' -e 's,</(kref|sub)>,!/\1>,g' |
 yq -p=xml -o=yaml |
 sed -E -e 's/!(kref|sub)>/<\1>/g' -e 's,!/(kref|sub)>,</\1>,g'
```

Your sed might want a different option for regex processing.
Or you could use some other text-mangling tool,
such as jq:

```
jq -Rr 'gsub("<(?<tag>kref|sub)>"; "!\(.tag)>") | gsub("</(?<tag>kref|sub)>"; "!\(.tag)>")' |
 yq -p=xml -o=yaml |
 jq -Rr 'gsub("!(?<tag>kref|sub)>"; "<\(.tag)>") | gsub("!/(<tag>kref|sub)>"; "</\(.tag)>")'
```